# Extracting keywords in url

Tags: php, regex

How do i extract a keyword from url in PHP?

example:

http://example.com/item/search/shoes/
http://example.com/item/search/shoes/page/3/

The extracted keyword of the above urls should be shoes

any help is highly appreciated.

fgwapo

Comment: `\/search\/\K[^\/]+`

Comment: you want the word searched. Is it? Please tell what do you mean by "keywords"? Is it a constant or, is your keywords stored in an array?

Comment: I won't submit this as an answer, because your tag suggests a regex solution, but if I were to suggest an alternative: `$uri = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);` to extract the path/uri, then, `$pathTokens = explode('/', $uri)` to get the path elements. If you want to check for your keyword you can do `in_array('shoes', $pathTokens)` or `$pathTokens[1] === 'shoes'`

Comment: @Darragh it's good to see an alternative approach to problem solving this :-)

Answer (score 1):

see `parse_url` http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

and work (explode away ) with the `path` component of the return from `parse_url`

Answer (score -1):

```
$keywords = explode("/", $HTTP_SERVER_VARS['REQUEST_URI']);

//$keywords[1] = example.com
//$keywords[2] = item
//$keywords[3] = search
//$keywords[4] = shoes
//$keywords[5] = page
//$keywords[6] = 3
```

Comment: `$HTTP_SERVER_VARS`, really? REALLY? are you gently taking the biscuit from OP? This isn't deprecated this has actually been removed as of PHP 5.4 and is ***highly*** discouraged.